# Select items from List of objects that are tuples

Tags: c#

I have a class that looks like so;

```
class MessageEntry
{
    public Tuple<bool, int> MessageId;

    public Tuple<bool, DateTime> MessageDate { get; internal set; }
    public Tuple<bool, String> Subject { get; internal set; }
    public Tuple<bool, String> EmailFrom { get; internal set; }
    public Tuple<bool, String> EmailTo { get; internal set; }
    public Tuple<bool, String> EmailCC { get; internal set; }
    public Tuple<bool, String> EmailBCC { get; internal set; }
    public Tuple<bool, String> EmailDateSent { get; internal set; }
    public Tuple<bool, String> BodyHTML { get; internal set; }
}
```

I then have a `List<MessageEntry>` - `List<MessageEntry> test = new List<MessageEntry>`.

How can I select all items frrom `test` where `Item1` of the tuples is `true`?

Comment: I suggest you turn  off your computer. Get a piece of paper and pencil and try to explain what you want to do in English. Imagine the list is a large deck of cards. How would you find the items in this "deck"?

Comment: question: why are all of the fields tuples? What purpose does this serve?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to only write the ones that are 'true' to a CSV, the others can be disregarded.

Comment: not a fan of the first comment, but the second one makes sense: perhaps it helps with selection, but you're creating problems when time to consume your MessageEntry properties. !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Subject) and the like would probably achieve what you're after for your selection if you made them the underlying data type

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Where do the tuples come from? Why do you have tuples at all? Why not just plain types for each field?

Comment: You could replace tuples with nullables.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = test.Where(x => x.MessageDate.Item1 && x.Subject.Item1 && ....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand how you plan to use the code from the question.
But I think this code can help you if you change it to your own needs.

**EDIT (I extract check method in extension method, for using in LINQ like style):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new List<MessageEntry>();

            var result = test
                .Where(entry => entry.IsAllTuplePropertiesIsTrue())
                .Aggregate(
                    string.Empty, 
                    (s, entry) => s + $"value is {entry.IsAllTuplePropertiesIsTrue()}"
                    );

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class MessageEntryExtension
    {
        private const BindingFlags BindingFlags = 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty
            | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
            | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance;

        /// <summary>
        /// Method check all <see cref="Tuple" /> properties 
        /// in instance of <see cref="MessageEntry" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="messageEntry"></param>
        /// <returns>If one of several Tuple.Item1 value is not bool false not equal 
        /// false - return false. Any way - true</returns>
        public static bool IsAllTuplePropertiesIsTrue(this MessageEntry messageEntry)
        {
            var props = typeof (MessageEntry).GetProperties(BindingFlags);

            foreach (var value in props.Select(p => p.GetValue(messageEntry)))
            {
                if (value == null)
                    return false;

                if (typeof (Tuple<,>) == value.GetType())
                    return false;

                var item1Type = value.GetType().GetProperty("Item1", BindingFlags);
                var item1Value = item1Type?.GetValue(value);

                if (!(item1Value is bool))
                    return false;

                if (!(bool) item1Value)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MessageEntry
    {
        public MessageEntry()
        {
            MessageId = new Tuple<bool, int>(true, 1);
            MessageDate = new Tuple<bool, DateTime>(false, DateTime.Now);
            Subject = new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "Hello, World!");
        }

        // Pay attention, I changed this place, 
        // so as not to duplicate the reflection code. 
        // For properties and field, it is similar, but still disconnects
        public Tuple<bool, int> MessageId { get; internal set; }

        public Tuple<bool, DateTime> MessageDate { get; internal set; }
        public Tuple<bool, string> Subject { get; internal set; }
        public Tuple<bool, string> EmailFrom { get; internal set; }
        public Tuple<bool, string> EmailTo { get; internal set; }
        public Tuple<bool, string> EmailCC { get; internal set; }
        public Tuple<bool, string> EmailBCC { get; internal set; }
        public Tuple<bool, string> EmailDateSent { get; internal set; }
        public Tuple<bool, string> BodyHTML { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```